# Django - sort a previously filtered list

Tags: django

I'm a real noob to programming and I want to make sure that this approach is solid enough.

I want to filter search results for my model and then allow users to sort the results according to various variables.  My thought was to attach the filter variables as GET parameters to the sort link (which would then have unique sort variables).

I've looked on other sites and it seems as though there is probably a more elegant solution (they don't contain huge querystrings).

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the querystrings you can use Django's url routing. The challenge is then going to be to generate appropriate urls for your links.

Django has a handy [url template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url). You can use it to determine the url for your given the name of the url and it's parameters.

In your urls.py you might have something like:

```
url(r'^sort/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'funkysort', name='funkysort'),
```

I'm using the [url function](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url)** in my urlconf (urls.py) to make it easier to name my url. I'm naming my url for the sake of the {% url %} template tag.

In your template you can then do:

```
{% url funkysort 5 10 %}
```

and Django will generate something like:

```
/mysite/sort/5/10/
```

**Note: This is different than the url template tag. If you want to do the equivalent of the url template tag in your code, use the [reverse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function.

Comment: huh, I didn't know about sending parmeters to the url function in that way, that's useful.

Comment: At the end of the day, though, I'll still need to attach all the variables with this method, it seems.  I'll just do so through url routing, rather than GET parameters, right?

Comment: I prefer GET for sorting because it merely modifies the output of an individual page, where to me, different urls imply distinctly separate content. I'm sure everybody has their own opinion here.

Comment: YUJI makes a good point. The quick and dirty thing is to write out the parameters by hand. There's a more elegant solution here that gets into writing a custom template tag ( url doesn't support it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778247/how-do-i-construct-a-django-reverse-url-using-query-args

Answer (score 0):

Django's admin uses indexes like o=3  if you'd like to shorten it.

You could map sort fields to an index or an otherwise prettier name.

```
sorts = {
    0: 'field1',
    1: 'field2',
    2: 'field3',
}

qs = qs.order_by(sorts.get(request.GET.get('o'), 'id'))
```

You'd need to add the ascending / descending code as well but that's just a quick example.