# How do i pass GET parameters using django urlresolvers reverse

Tags: django, get, reverse

I am using django 1.2 and going from one view to another using the urlresolvers reverse method.

```
url = reverse(viewOne)
```

and I want to pass a get parameter, for example

> name = 'joe'

so that in the viewOne if I do

```
def viewOne(request):
    request.GET['name']
```

I will get

```
joe
```

how do I do that ?

Comment: Take a look at [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5341769/301373) that gives a rather nice way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I created a feature request: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25582

Answer (score 162, accepted):

GET parameters have nothing to do with the URL as returned by `reverse`. Just add it on at the end:

```
url = "%s?name=joe" % reverse(viewOne)
```

Comment: This works for this example. Since no quoting gets done, this fails if you use values which need to be quoted.

Answer (score 84):

A safer and more flexible way:

```
import urllib
from django.urls import reverse


def build_url(*args, **kwargs):
    get = kwargs.pop('get', {})
    url = reverse(*args, **kwargs)
    if get:
        url += '?' + urllib.urlencode(get)
    return url
```

then you can use `build_url`:

```
url = build_url('view-name', get={'name': 'joe'})
```

which takes same arguments as `reverse`, but provides an extra keyword argument `get` where you can put your `GET` parameters in it as a dictionary.

Comment: Note: Django's `django.utils.http.urlencode` function might be preferable since it is a "version of Python’s urllib.urlencode() function that can operate on unicode string": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlencode

Comment: I would rename this function to `reverse_with_params()` or something similar.

Answer (score 22):

This is very similar to Amir's solution but handles lists as well.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import QueryDict

def build_url(*args, **kwargs):
    params = kwargs.pop('params', {})
    url = reverse(*args, **kwargs)
    if not params: return url

    qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
    for k, v in params.iteritems():
        if type(v) is list: qdict.setlist(k, v)
        else: qdict[k] = v

    return url + '?' + qdict.urlencode()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> build_url('member-list', params={'format': 'html', 'sex': ['male', 'female']})
u'/members/?format=html&sex=male&sex=female'
```

Comment: What's the point of having `sex=male&sex=female`? I think it should be `&sex[]=female&sex[]=female` (note the additional `[]`), to be a GET request array

Comment: @potatoes The ``[]`` are a PHP convention.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the delayed correction on this.

While both the answers here handles the required task too well, i think just a simple function to urlencode a dictionary is the most flexible way of doing this:

```
import urllib

def getify(dic):
    st = ''
    for K, V in dic.items():
        K = urllib.parse.quote(str(K))
        if isinstance(V, list):
            for v in V:
                st += K + '=' + urllib.parse.quote(str(v)) + '&'
        else:
            st += K + '=' + urllib.parse.quote(str(V)) + '&'
    return st.rstrip('&')
```

Comment: This does *not* urlencode the dictionary - there is no handling of URL reserved characters (e.g. `#`, `?`) or any type of percent encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding