# Using resolve on url with query params in django

Tags: django, url

Using resolve on a url without query params result in

```
resolve('/tracking/url/')
ResolverMatch(func=<function tracking_url_url at 0x028D62B0>, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name='tracking-url-url', app_name='None', namespace='')
```

Using resolve on a url with query params (the url works in the browser) results in an `Resolver404` error

```
resolve('/tracking/url/?url=home')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 476, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 352, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
```

The URL entry is

```
url(r'^tracking/url/$', 'myauth.views.tracking_url_url', name='tracking-url-url'),
```

What is the best way to resolve a url with query params and get a dict of the qs the same way i'm getting it from a regular request, e.g, `request.GET.get('url')`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`resolve()` and `reverse()` do not work on query parameters.

What you can do is: Resolve URL and then append your query parameter

`"%s?url=home", resolve('/tracking/url/')` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585579/1428424))

If you want to use `request.GET.get(...)`, why don't you redirect to a view which uses `request.GET.get(...)`?

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def someViewFunction():
    ...
    url = "%s?url=home", resolve('/tracking/url/')
    return redirect(url)
```

If this does not help, try specifying your problem.

Comment: There must be a function django uses to resolve url's into view_name & query parameters. Seems like i need to do some digging in the source.