# Alternative to urllib.urlencode for building a url from a dict

Tags: django, urllib, urlencode, percent-encoding

Im testing a redirection (login required) on a view.

Test snippet:

```
...
expected_url = build_url(
    self.login_url,
    get={'next': self.url}
)
self.assertRedirects(
    response,
    expected_url,
    status_code=302
)
```

I get `AssertionError` because `expected_url` is percent encoded, the one django is displaying through `login_required` (`django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required`) is not percent-encoded.

So I get:

```
AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/log_in/?next=/payments/purchase/'
expected 'http://testserver/log_in/?next=payments%3Apurchase'
```

I have my `build_url` func as described below. Im encoding a `dict` with `urllib.urlencode`.

`build_url` source: [How do i pass GET parameters using django urlresolvers reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585491/how-do-i-pass-get-parameters-using-django-urlresolvers-reverse)

```
def build_url(*args, **kwargs):
    get = kwargs.pop('get', {})
    url = reverse(*args, **kwargs)
    if get:
        url += '?' + urllib.urlencode(get)
    return url
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to tell django to display `login_url` percent-encoded?
- Should I use something instead `urllib.urlencode` to build a url from
  a `dict`?
- Is percent-encoding important so I must follow it?

Comment: The unencoded urls are _not_ the same. The redirect contains `next=/payments/purchase/`, while the expected url contains `next=payments:purchase`. I believe `assertRedirects` will decode the urls before comparing them.

Comment: I forgot to reverse `self.url`. But Im still getting exception. `AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/log_in/?next=/payments/purchase/', expected 'http://testserver/log_in/?next=%2Fpayments%2Fpurchase%2F'`