# Pass GET parameters through django's render() shortcut

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a date filter that I am passing through several django views:

**views.py**

```
def event_list(request):
    date_query = request.GET.get("date", str(default_event_date()))
    d = datetime.strptime(date_query, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    # do stuff...

    return render(request, "events/event_list.html", context)
```

But I would like to carry forward the GET parameters through the `render()`.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585491/how-do-i-pass-get-parameters-using-django-urlresolvers-reverse) for how to do this using `reverse()`, but `render()` doesn't take a url directly.

I suspect I need to add it back in to the `request` that is passed, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "carry forward through render ()" ???

Comment: I mean, after I render, I want the url to have `?date=2016-12-30` at the end

Comment: Could you also please paste the snippet of the relevant portion of your urls.py file?

Comment: `url(r'^$', views.event_list, name='list'),`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding `render`.  `render`’s job in life is to return an `HttpResponse` with [content to the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) from an HTML template and a context dictionary:

> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary 
>   and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

In contrast, `redirect` redirects the user to a new URL (i.e., so `GET` parameters can be included).  Thus, if you use `render`, you have to preserve your `GET` parmeters manually.  Of course, you can avoid this by adding `date` to the user’s session by doing something like:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

date_query = request.session.get('date')
if not date_query:
    date_query = request.GET.get("date", default_event_date())
    if not isinstance(date_query, date):
        date_query = datetime.strptime(date_query, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    request.session['date'] = date_query

d = date_query
```

And this will let you “carry forward” your GET parameters to subsequent routes and views.

Comment: How do I preserve the `GET` parameters manually?  Apologies for the poorly worded question, but that's what I meant.

Comment: The GET parameters shouldn’t change for this particular render.  They should only change on page turn from the rendered page to the next page.  So preserving your GET parameters means formatting your query string (using `request.GET.urlencode`) and appending it to each URL on which you would like the `date` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the session suggestion.  I think this might be a better solution anyway.  I'm going to try it out.